# Files in the CRM 2011 ISV folder cannot find codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am doing a `CRM 4.0` to 2011 upgrade and there are files in the `CRMWeb` folder on the 4.0 setup (in a `subdirectory`, not the `"ISV"` folder though) that I cannot migrate to the `CRM` 2011 setup. Long story short, I load these web application files into `CRM` 2011's `"ISV"` folder but I keep getting an error that the codebehind file cannot be found (specifically that the "inherits" portion cannot be found.

I believe I am supposed to create a new `IIS` site going forward but I wanted to see if anyone knew of a permission issue or something that might be causing this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To quote MSDN:

> Adding custom webpages and supporting files to the \ISV\ folder is fully supported but *deprecated*. The ISV folder is maintained for backward (legacy) compatibility only. Any webpages or other custom code in that folder must use the 2007 web service endpoint. For more iformation, see [Upgrade Code in the ISV folder to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309571(v=crm.5).aspx) and [Use the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 (2007) Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334316(v=crm.5).aspx).

**- [Supported Extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328350(v=crm.5).aspx)**